# Intercept URL parameters and store them in a service

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to intercept the entered URL, getting its parameters, storing them in a service (that can be used by other services) then redirecting to `/`.

```
var config = function (AppConfig, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'ngInject';

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                var params = $location.search(); //How can I store these params ?
            }

        }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(AppConfig.defaultRoute);

};
```

Comment: declare a variable in the root scope and use to keep the data. or you could use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` depending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a service or a factory to store those values, and then add this service as a dependency for the other services;

```
.service('storedURLs', function() {
    var urls= [];
    return {
        add: function(newURL) {
            urls.push(newURL);
        },
        geturls: function() {
            return urls;
        }
    };
})
```

And, inside your interceptor you could use:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q, $location, $injector) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                var params = $location.search();
                var urlService= $injector.get('storedURLs'); 
                urlService.add(params);
            }

        }
    });
```